# Call to a member function find() on a non-object while trying to scrape a website

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

This is the code I am using to parse a website. However, sometimes I get the error message `Call to a member function find() on a non-object`. Why is this happening?

```
require '../../img/simple_html_dom.php';
$searchterm = $_GET['id'];

$url = "http://bdlpdtr.com/listings-$searchterm";
$html = file_get_html( $url );

$posts = $html->find('div[class=fl lftSec mt45]');

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    $postedon = $post->find('span',6);
    $walkdate = $post->find('div[class=p]',1);
    $walkdatefull = $walkdate->find('span',0);
    $walktimefull = $walkdate->find('span',1);
```

In the page to be scraped, if Walkdate is there it is working and if Walkdate is not there it is showing the above error.

Comment: If it sometimes works and sometimes not, you will probably do not have the `div` with class "fl lftSec mt45" everywhere. Are you trying to scrape that website?

Comment: yes, i am scrapping. if class is there it is working. if class is not there, not working. some pages have class and some pages are not having class.

Comment: Well, then you either need to change your pattern to search for (`'div[class=fl lftSec mt45]'`) or catch the error if it is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, i got the answer from this site. i have just added

```
if(!empty($walkdate)) {

    $walkdatefull = $walkdate->find('span',0);
    $walktimefull = $walkdate->find('span',1);

    }
```

and it is working.